# unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll'

Tags: r-package, loadlibrary, modulenotfounderror, dllnotfoundexception

[![
Hi there!!

I am using R 4.0.5 on a windows 10 OS

I have installed rtools40-x86_64 and used the following command to put the location of the *make it* utilities as recommanded [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

```
writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

However after restarting R, it gave me the error on the picture below. or the following

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I have uninstalled R, RStudio, Rtools, deleted all related files in C, Documents, and RStudio registry, and reinstalled there after. But the same error persist.

In a [related post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-car-package-in-r/14922) they made mentioned of missing binaries, and I used the command

```
install.packages("stats", type = "binary")
```

but it was negative.

I tried updating stats package, but once I call it it gives the same error.

```
> update.packages("stats")
> library(stats)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Every package which requires stats package gives the exact same error.

Does anyone have any idea on how to overcome this challenge?

Thanks in advance.
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjO0I.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjO0I.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed a previous version of R (3.6.0) and a previous version of Rtools (.35) and that message disappeared. I have not tried any other R version.

Comment: I also work around the issue by reverted to my previous version (R 4.0.3), but would like to know how to get a functional updates.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen many suggestions here and elsewhere suggesting to delete the .Renviron files. I deleted .Renviron locally with no success. However, I found an additional two .Renviron file in my OneDrive folder.

After deleting these files in OneDrive and reinstalling the most recent versions of R and rtools I was able to avoid the ‘stats.dll’ error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Go to files. Delete the `.Renviron` file that you created and it will work.

Comment: I have the same issue as Andy. Deleting the .Renviron file does not fix it.

Comment: Contributor [@Halima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16352232/halima) reports that this works in R 4.1.0 on Windows 10. (They posted this as [a repeat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68198900/3025856), so I'm reiterating their confirmation here since I assume their answer will get deleted.)